# running a command in Raspberry Pi boot

Tags: raspberry-pi

I tried 3 different method no succeded for running the code

```
cd amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/build
./kvs_gstreamer_sample PiStream
```

we get following errors

> [09-12-2020 15:06:12:496.703 GMT] Using region: us-west-2 [ERROR]
> [09-12-2020 15:06:12:514.317 GMT] No valid credential method was found
> [ERROR] [09-12-2020 15:06:12:515.086 GMT] Failed to initialize kinesis
> video with an exception: No valid credential method was found

I am trying to run a cpp code which has some AWS dependencies which says we could not define the paths in the boot even though we added in 3 different method

adding commands  into local.rc
adding  crontab -e
and adding bash.rc

after booting ia can run the comman from terminal successfully.

How can we define the some parameters in the booth of raspberry pi

Comment: More information is required to answer what should be a more clear question. What are does the app code do? In short, you require to have credentials setup for AWS activities. This may be done in several ways.

Comment: If you are not passing the credentials within the application, then you must set default credentials to be used with requests ... most likely `aws configure` from the command line will allow you to configure this but it does not solve every situation.